# JavaScript reference to anonymous function from inside that function

Tags: javascript, events

I'm creating a small canvas library in which I have an anonymous function which needs to reference to itself. However, I don't know how to do this. I have the following incomplete code:

```
var removeDragHandler = (function (object) {
  return function (e) {
    if (typeof object["dragend"] === "function") {
      object["dragend"](e);
    }
    removeEvent({
      element: window,
      event: "mousemove",
      callback: object["drag"]
    });
    removeEvent({
      element: window,
      event: "mouseup",
      callback: ????? //What here?
    });
  };
})(object);
addEvent({
  element: window,
  event: "mouseup",
  callback: removeDragHandler
});
```

Of course I could replace the ????? with arguments.callee, but then it doesn't work in strict mode. Are there any other options?

Comment: If your problem is just referencing the anonymous function, you should ask for that and not for "self deleting events".

Comment: @Bergi :P so true, I had to read it twice to get the actual useful info from there which is *Of course I could replace the ????? with arguments.callee, but then it doesn't work in strict mode*

Comment: @Bergi - You're right, I updated my post and deleted all irrelevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a name to the anonymous function. Note that there is a bug in older IE where the anonymous function leaks as a declared function in the outer scope but that should not be issue here since that outer scope is pretty empty anyway.

```
var removeDragHandler = (function (object) {
  return function once(e) {
    if (typeof object["dragend"] === "function") {
      object["dragend"](e);
    }
    removeEvent({
      element: window,
      event: "mousemove",
      callback: object["drag"]
    });
    removeEvent({
      element: window,
      event: "mouseup",
      callback: once
    });
  };
})(object);
```

Comment: Of course, I can't believe I didn't think of that myself. I don't really worry about older IE versions, since this is a small library for the canvas element. Older IE versions don't support the canvas element and hence can't use this library at all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you can avoid the IE leak by just storing the funcion in a variable instead of declaring it. Just do "var once; return once = function ..."

Comment: @Jbm true but then it's not NFE :(

Comment: Can I get a link to inner functions leaking to the outer scope in IE?